# How do I remove partitioning?

Tags: mysql, partitioning, mysql-5.6

There is a table `my_table` which has not been created any partition in MySQL 5.6. And I'm trying to create partitions by procedure in `my_table`, when I run this code:

```
alter table my_table remove partitioning
```

I'm getting this error:

```
1505 - Partition management on a not partitioned table is not possible
```

But when I run above code in MySQL version 5.5, this code can be run.

If my_table has been created partitions, and when I run above code, not only MySQL 5.5 can run, but also MySQL 5.6 can run too.

I guess that if this code can be run, MySQL 5.6 need to be config some files.But I am not able to why.

Can you solve it?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I would use the mechanism that you're using to purge old data, but since that's what you want to do, there is a way to work around this.

What you are seeing appears to be an undocumented incompatible change in behavior between MySQL 5.5 and MySQL 5.6 -- although, arguably, the real problem is that the statement should not be valid in MySQL 5.5 either when the table is not partitioned.

I confirmed the behavior you are seeing with MySQL 5.5.30 (no error) and 5.6.10 (error).

> I'm trying to create partitions by procedure

Do you mean in a Stored Procedure?

If that's the case, then you could use a [`CONTINUE HANDLER`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/declare-handler.html) specifically written to allow your stored procedure to ignore that one specific error code.

The following works in both MySQL 5.5 and 5.6.

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `test`.`test_continue_handler` $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `test`.`test_continue_handler` ()
BEGIN

  -- you may have some code that executes before the ALTER TABLE, here

  BEGIN
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR 1505 BEGIN END;
    ALTER TABLE t1 REMOVE PARTITIONING;
  END;

  SELECT 'that worked okay' AS message; -- remove this, your usual code after the ALTER TABLE goes here

END $$

DELIMITER ;

mysql> call test_continue_handler;
+------------------+
| message          |
+------------------+
| that worked okay |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.06 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.07 sec)
```

The `BEGIN END;` after `1505` is telling the server "when this error occurs, run the code that appears in this empty block instead of throwing an error."  There's no code between `BEGIN` and `END` but MySQL doesn't care and this results in suppressing error 1505.

The `BEGIN` and `END;` before "`DECLARE`..." and after "`ALTER`..." limit the scope of that `CONTINUE HANDLER` to only the single `ALTER TABLE` so that any other statements throwing that same error code later in your stored procedure (or in any procedure called by your procedure) will *not* be ignored.  Note this does *not* mean statements after the `ALTER TABLE` but before the next `END` will not be executed if an error occurs -- they will.  It only means that after the `END;`, the `CONTINUE HANDLER` will be out of scope and will not trap subsequent errors.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax to partition a table is this :

```
ALTER TABLE t1
    PARTITION BY HASH(id)
    PARTITIONS 8;
```

But i recommend to read carefully the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-table-partition-operations.html) first .

Before you partition a table you first need to think :

- on what field the partition of data will be made (ex: by date, by user etc) this is crucial since it can improve your performance dramatically if you choose the right field
- what algorithm to use to partition the data , you need to read this [chapter](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning.html) in order to make the best decision since it's NOT a general rule by which you partition a table.

Comment: Thank you,Stephan.when MySql-Event call procedure whice will remove all partition,and I want to dynamically create partitions by procedure. My flow chart is 'remove all partitions'->'create new partitions'->'remove all partitions'.

Comment: but what is the purpose of this? remove->create->remove ?

Comment: Sorry,I can't describe clearly just now. My purpose is that: I create an event,and this event will call procedure, and when calling procedure,which will check up the other table my_partition_table,if my_partition_table has not record about table my_table,procedure will remove all partitions in my_table,and then create new partitions;If my_partition_table has record,procedure will add partition,and execute code:'alter table my_table add partion(...);'.

Comment: My ultimate goal is keepping my_table's data within two months.

Comment: i see... then you can add a partition per month and drop the third one every month ... you don't need to drop all and create all

Comment: My ultimate goal is keepping my_table's data within two months.And if my_table has exists partition, when after procedure add partition,procedure would drop old partition.

Comment: yeah... something like that

Comment: 'i see... you don't need to drop all and create all'.I can do it according to what you said.But When created table my_mytable,my_mytable's structure just is 'create table my_mytable(...);',and not exists partition. Then created table,procedure will be call at the second day, and procedure will check up the other table my_partition_table,if my_partition_table has not record about table my_table,procedure will remove all partitions in my_table,and then create new partitions;If my_partition_table has record,procedure will add partition,and execute code:'alter table my_table add partion(...);'.

Comment: My English is poor,and often appear chinese style.I hope u can understand what I said.For what I said just now,in a word,when created a table,how to make table's partition from none to have.

Comment: its simple you will have a table with 2 partitions : one for current month and one for past month and when the month will change you have to do 2 things : add the partition for current month (alter table add partition...) and drop the last partition ( alter table frop partition ...)

Comment: yeah...I make things complicated and I am so 囧(this word is chinese.haa),thank your idea.Good luck Stephan.

Comment: glad i could help, i hope you will reach a working solution

Answer (score 0):

Stephan and Michael-sqlbot,thank you. 
According to Stephan said, when before running procedure,I have created partition in table.And it can run normally.
And According to Michael-sqlbot said,I modified my procedure and added code:‘DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR 1505 BEGIN END;’ in my procedure;And so, I did not created partition in table before running procedure,and procedure can run normally too.
Compared above two ways,I choosed Michael-sqlbot's way.It solves that the problem with the first run by this way. Thank you two again.
The following is my procedure after modified:

```
    -- general_procedure
    create procedure general_procedure(in tablenamein varchar(50),in intervalHour int,in newIntervalNum int)
general_pro:begin 
    declare maxMonitTime datetime default SYSDATE();
    declare maxMonitTimeStr varchar(50);
    declare minMonitTime datetime default SYSDATE();
    declare minMonitTimeStr varchar(50);
    declare recoidNum int default 0;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR 1505 BEGIN END;
    if tablenamein is null then 
        leave general_pro;
    end if;
    if intervalHour <= 0 then 
        set intervalHour = 6;
    end if;
    if newIntervalNum <= 0 then 
        set newIntervalNum = 1;
    end if;

    select count(*) into recoidNum from table_fen_qu where tablename=tablenamein and backupflag=0;
    if recoidNum > 0 then 
        select monittime into maxMonitTime from table_fen_qu where tablename=tablenamein and backupflag=0 order by monittime desc limit 1;
        if maxMonitTime is null then 
            set maxMonitTime = SYSDATE();
        end if;
        set recoidNum = timestampdiff(hour,SYSDATE(),DATE_SUB(maxMonitTime,INTERVAL 3 DAY));

        if recoidNum <= 0 then
            set recoidNum = 1; 
            while recoidNum <= newIntervalNum do 
                set maxMonitTime = ADDDATE(maxMonitTime,INTERVAL intervalHour HOUR);
                set maxMonitTimeStr = CONCAT('p',DATE_FORMAT(maxMonitTime,"%Y%m%d%H%i%s"));
                set @v_add_s = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ',tablenamein,' ADD PARTITION  (PARTITION ',maxMonitTimeStr,' VALUES LESS THAN (\'',maxMonitTime,'\') ENGINE = InnoDB )');
                prepare stmt from @v_add_s;
                execute stmt; 
                deallocate prepare stmt;
                insert into table_fen_qu(fenquname,tablename,monittime,backupflag) VALUES(maxMonitTimeStr,tablenamein,maxMonitTime,0);
                set recoidNum = recoidNum + 1;
            end while;
        end if;
    else
        set @v_del_s = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ',tablenamein,' remove partitioning');
        prepare stmt from @v_del_s;
        execute stmt; 
        deallocate prepare stmt;
        delete from table_fen_qu where tablename = tablenamein;
        set @sele = CONCAT('select min(moint_time),max(moint_time) into @mintime,@maxtime from ',tablenamein);
        prepare stmt from @sele;
        execute stmt; 
        deallocate prepare stmt;
        set minMonitTime = @mintime;
        set maxMonitTime = @maxtime;
        if minMonitTime is null then 
            set minMonitTimeStr = CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(ADDDATE(SYSDATE(),INTERVAL 4 DAY),'%Y-%m-%d'),' 00:00:00');
            set minMonitTime = STR_TO_DATE(minMonitTimeStr,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s');
            set minMonitTimeStr = CONCAT('p',DATE_FORMAT(minMonitTime,"%Y%m%d%H%i%s"));
            set @v_add_s = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ',tablenamein,' PARTITION BY RANGE COLUMNS(moint_time) (PARTITION ',minMonitTimeStr,' VALUES LESS THAN (\'',minMonitTime,'\') ENGINE = InnoDB);');
            prepare stmt from @v_add_s;
            execute stmt; 
            deallocate prepare stmt;
            insert into table_fen_qu(fenquname,tablename,monittime,backupflag) VALUES(minMonitTimeStr,tablenamein,minMonitTime,0);
        else 
            set recoidNum = 2; 
            set minMonitTimeStr = CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(minMonitTime,'%Y-%m-%d'),' 00:00:00');
            set minMonitTime = STR_TO_DATE(minMonitTimeStr,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s');
            set maxMonitTimeStr = CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(ADDDATE(maxMonitTime,INTERVAL 4 DAY),'%Y-%m-%d'),' 00:00:00');
            set maxMonitTime = STR_TO_DATE(maxMonitTimeStr,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s');
            set newIntervalNum = floor(timestampdiff(hour,minMonitTime,maxMonitTime) / intervalHour) + 1;
            if newIntervalNum < 12 then
                set newIntervalNum = 12;
            end if;
            set minMonitTimeStr = CONCAT('p',DATE_FORMAT(minMonitTime,"%Y%m%d%H%i%s"));
            set @v_add_s = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ',tablenamein,' PARTITION BY RANGE COLUMNS(moint_time) (PARTITION ',minMonitTimeStr,' VALUES LESS THAN (\'',minMonitTime,'\') ENGINE = InnoDB,');
            insert into table_fen_qu(fenquname,tablename,monittime,backupflag) VALUES(minMonitTimeStr,tablenamein,minMonitTime,0);
            while recoidNum <= newIntervalNum do 
                set minMonitTime = ADDDATE(minMonitTime,INTERVAL intervalHour HOUR);
                set minMonitTimeStr = CONCAT('p',DATE_FORMAT(minMonitTime,"%Y%m%d%H%i%s"));
                set @v_add_s = CONCAT(@v_add_s,'PARTITION ',minMonitTimeStr,' VALUES LESS THAN (\'',minMonitTime,'\') ENGINE = InnoDB,');
                insert into table_fen_qu(fenquname,tablename,monittime,backupflag) VALUES(minMonitTimeStr,tablenamein,minMonitTime,0);
                set recoidNum = recoidNum + 1;
            end while;
            set @v_add_s = left(@v_add_s,LENGTH(@v_add_s)-1);
            set @v_add_s = CONCAT(@v_add_s,');');
            prepare stmt from @v_add_s;
            execute stmt; 
            deallocate prepare stmt;
        end if;
    end if;
end general_pro;
```